# POST with special char using Retrofit

Tags: java, retrofit

I need to send a POST request with a body like this:

```
{
  "@class": ".RegistrationRequest",
  "displayName": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "requestId": "string",
  "segments": {},
  "userName": "string"
}
```

My Interface class is:

```
public interface GSInterface {

    @POST(ENDPOINT_REGISTER)
    Call<RegistrationResponse> postRegister(
            @Field("@class") String gsclass,
            @Body User user);
}
```

I cant create a parameter "@class" inside the user object, at least I dont know how.

Also, put "@class" as @Field, @Part or @Query doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@SerializedName` annotation to provide field names.

```
class User {
  @SerializedName("@class")
  private String gsClass;
  ...
}
```